# How do I display varchar date string with mixed format to another format?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I am using SQL server 2008 R2. I know I can use CONVERT with different format code as the third parameter to do the conversion to DATETIME first and CONVERT again to VARCHAR with another format code to change the display format.

The real problem now is I have mixed raw data in a single column. So my question is how do you write a single SELECT statement to display from mixed YYYY/MM/DD, DD/MM/YYYY all to DD/MM/YYYY?

I tried to use ISDATE() but it think 31/01/2013 is not a date while 01/01/2013 is a date. Now I could only think of to see if the YYYY is on the left or on the right to determine the correct input format, but I dont know how to write it out in a single SELECT statement.

*Any procedure to change the format first then do a simple SELECT is not an option. I am not allowed to change the source.*

Thank you

Comment: You write `CASE` statements to check whether the 3rd character is an integer. If it is, then you know the first set is not a year.

Comment: I like yours! Brilliant!

Comment: You really should fight to remove the restriction to change the source. Nobody in their right mind should be storing dates of various formats as strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that only those 2 formats (yyyy/mm/dd and dd/mm/yyyy) exist in the data, then you could probably get away with a `CASE` statement along the lines of:

```
CASE
  WHEN (SUBSTRING(dateColumn, 5, 1) = '/') THEN CONVERT(datetime, dateColumn, 111)
  ELSE CONVERT(datetime, dateColumn, 103)
END
```

Comment: Right now there are only two variants and junks (not date format at all). I hope this would suffice.

Comment: @camila_c . . . Aaron is being nice.  Your response is not syntactically correct SQL and it is not SQL compatible with SQL Server.  The third argument to `convert` is an integer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, wasn't paying attention and forgot that format is an integer value. Updated with corrections.

Comment: Please test your code samples before posting, especially ones this simple, which take about 4 seconds to test. With three up-votes in the first three minutes, it is quite likely that some reader came along and thought they had discovered some new extension to `CONVERT`...

Comment: @chamila_c: You are still missing the `END` from the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use string manipulations?  Something like:

```
select (case when substring(d, 5, 1) = '/'  -- YYYY/MM/DD
             then right(d, 2)+'/'+substring(6, 2)+'/'+left(d, 4)
             else d
        end)
```

By the way, if you are choosing formats for dates when represented as strings, I highly recommend YYYY-MM-DD (or YYYY/MM/DD) because comparison operators work on them.

Comment: Thank you! I dont know which one is better, but may be converting to date is easier to maintain in the future if I really want to change to another date format for display (just change the last format code)